# Name of class property to string

Tags: c#, string, properties

I have searched endlessly for a thread that specifies exactly my question but I cannot find it.

I want to take a class property and just take the property out of it as a string!

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo ()
   {
   }
   public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to have the string "MyProperty" in the end, something like this:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
string s = Helperfunction(f.MyProperty);

string Helperfunction(  X  )
{
   string MyString;
   //do something with X
   return MyString;
}
```

How difficult would this be to realize just with maybe a helperfunction?
So the output should be "MyProperty"

Because I dont want to hard code it, and as soon as I would ever refactor the property name, it would still work without editing the hardcoded string!

Comment: Whar are you actually trying to solve? Always if people are fiddling around with reflection i think that they instead should try to find a different approach.

Comment: If you are writting the property name in code, why not just pass it as a string?

Comment: @Gusman Because refactoring tools might not pick that up when renaming the property. As the OP said, "as soon as I would ever refactor the property name, it would still work without editing the hardcoded string...!"

Comment: Using R# can help solving the refactoring issue. :)

Comment: Doh, lazy eyes... did not read to the end, just saw the property coded and start to write.

Comment: well, the property value itself is an int... so im just trying to get the NAME of the property as string...!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the name, here is a helper class I use:

```
public static class MemberName
{
    /// <summary>
    /// *** WARNING - Uses reflection - use responsibly ***
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="instance"></param>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetMemberName<T>(this T instance, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        return GetMemberName(expression);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// *** WARNING - Uses reflection - use responsibly ***
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    public static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The expression cannot be null.");
        }

        return GetMemberName(expression.Body);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// *** WARNING - Uses reflection - use responsibly ***
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="instance"></param>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetMemberName<T>(this T instance, Expression<Action<T>> expression)
    {
        return GetMemberName(expression);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// *** WARNING - Uses reflection - use responsibly ***
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
    public static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The expression cannot be null.");
        }

        return GetMemberName(expression.Body);
    }

    private static string GetMemberName(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The expression cannot be null.");
        }

        if (expression is MemberExpression)
        {
            // Reference type property or field
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }

        if (expression is MethodCallExpression)
        {
            // Reference type method
            var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)expression;
            return methodCallExpression.Method.Name;
        }

        if (expression is UnaryExpression)
        {
            // Property, field of method returning value type
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression;
            return GetMemberName(unaryExpression);
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid expression");
    }

    private static string GetMemberName(UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
    {
        if (unaryExpression.Operand is MethodCallExpression)
        {
            var methodExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
            return methodExpression.Method.Name;
        }

        return ((MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand).Member.Name;
    }
}
```

And an example usage:

```
 string propName = MemberName.GetMemberName<Foo>(x => x.MyProperty);
```

Comment: this whole class is needed to just convert class.MyProperty to "MyProperty" ?

Comment: There was another answer with just that one method but it looks like it got removed. No the whole class is not needed, I'm sure you could do it with a single method. What's your concern with adding the whole class?

Comment: no concert, i was just amazed that it is still not totally simple..!
like indeed that other answer, but the other one wasn't working so..!
I will use yours, ill let you know in a sec

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand the question, but if you want to do something with the propertyname, you could have a look at the `CallerMemberName` attribute.

```
string Helperfunction([CallerMemberName]string X = null  )
{

   return "PropertyName: " + X;

}
```

If you call this method within a property getter, then it will output the name of the property:

```
public class Foo
{
     public string Foo { get { Trace.WriteLine (SomeFunction()); } }
}
```

Will output "MyProperty"